# Рисование на формочке

Tags: c#, graphics

Использую класс `Grahpics` в C# для рисования разных штук на формочке.
Делаю так:

```
Grahpics g = this.CreateGraphics();
```

и дальше что-то, типо `g.DrawLine()` и т. д.
Проблема в том, что изображение стирается, когда формочка заходит за границы экрана.
Как сделать, чтобы оно оставалось?

Answer (score 3):

1 - Если вы пишите свой контрол или что-то подобное (большую часть времени статичное) то перегружайте метод OnPaint

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("YEAH!", Font, Brushes.DarkOrchid, 10, 20);
    }
```

2 - Если делаете игру на winform + GDI (или динамический контрол), то рисуйте состояние по таймеру. Или переходите на XNA. ([Статья на хабре про быстрое рисование по таймеру](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164885/) )

Что бы не было мерцаний устанавливайте свойство DoubleBuffered

```
 DoubleBuffered = true;
```

3 - Если не хочется перерисовывать все каждый раз, то рисовать можно в картинку. А в onPaint ее отрисовывать на форму или контрол.

```
    public ctor() { // в конструкторе создаем картинку и Graphics
        bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    }

    public void somedraw() { // какое то рисование
        graphics.DrawString("Update form after this calling", Font, Brushes.GreenYellow, 1, 1);
        Invalidate(); // после того как закончили кусок отрисовки дернем этот метод
    }
    // вы зывается когда система хочет перерисовать окно или мы вызвали Invalidate()
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) { 
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0); // нарисуем все накопленное в картинке

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно постоянно перерисовывать картинку. Вешайте обработчик на подходящее Вам событие и профит. Только если слишком часто перерисовывать, то картинка будет мерцать. А вообще (скорее всего делается это на WinForm), сделайте на WPF - там все прелести DirectX. Но решать на какой платформе делать, конечно же, Вам.

Comment: +1 за WPF, -1 за "постоянно перерисовывать"